# Meaning of Function Involving Product of Sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The function is $h:R^2 \times R^2\rightarrow R \times R$ such that $h((a, b), (c, d)) = (a + b, c - d)$.

**What is the meaning of this function?**

Here are my thoughts:

$R^2$ is a mathematical object, say, a such that a = ($a_1, a_2$) for $a_1, a_2 \in R$.

The function maps the set product of $R^2$ objects to the set product of $R$ objects.

Right? This idea is simple enough. However, my main area of confusion arises from $h((a,b), (c,d)) = (a + b, c - d). $

If (a,b) and (c,d) are the tuples referred to in "$h:R^2 \times R^2\rightarrow R \times R$", what purpose does the set product serve here? The same goes for the result (a + b, c - d) - what is the meaning of the set product here?

Comment: The $\times$ here is not a "cross product", but the _cartesian product_ of sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it would clarify matters to observe that $R^2\times R^2$ is essentially identical to $R^4$, or on the other hand to $R\times R\times R\times R$. That is, $R^4$ consists of $4$-tuples from $R$, while $R^2\times R^2$ consists of pairs from $R^2$, that is, pairs each element of which is a pair from $R$-it's clear that these things are naturally equivalent to $4$-tuples from $R$. So you might rewrite your function as $h:R^4\to R^2, h(a,b,c,d)=(a+b,c-d)$. Why would you write it with domain $R^2\times R^2$, then? For aesthetic purposes, basically: sometimes you're really thinking about two points in a plane, rather than a single point in four-dimensional space, and so it's better to make that explicit in your notation.